# Server does not read Cordova FileTransfer options params

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having trouble with the FileTransfer method in Cordova. The function was working before, but now I have switched hosting provider, and the params I send with the options object does not work. The upload code I use is;

```
$scope.uploadPhoto = function() {

var img = document.getElementById('image');
var imageURI = img.src;
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
options.headers = {
   Connection: "close"
};
options.chunkedMode = false;

var params = new Object();

//$scope.username =  window.localStorage.getItem("uname");

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( 
    function(position) { 
      $scope.hideLoading();
      params.lon = position.coords.longitude;
      params.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      params.uname = $scope.username;
      alert(params.lon + ',' + params.lat); 

      options.params = params;

      var ft = new FileTransfer();
      ft.upload(imageURI, "http://file/to/upload.php", win, fail, options, true);
    }, 

    function() { 
      alert('Error getting location'); 
    }
);
```

}

And the server side PHP file is

```
$file_url = "\'http://path/to/{$new_image_name}\'";


//Set up the query and run it
//$myquery = " SELECT  `imgurl`, `lat`, `long` FROM  `pins` ";

$insert = " INSERT INTO pins VALUES ('$file_url', '$lat', '$lon', '$uname' ) ";

$query = mysqli_query($connection, $insert);

//Check the query worked
if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}
```

This code was working fine up until I switched server provider. It also inserts the $file_url parameter properly into the database, as that is set in the same PHP file, so the connection and insert to the database is working. The problem is the params that are sent with the FileTransfer options appear to be empty.

Could there a be a PHP configuration option that is not set, that should be? I'd really appreciate any help, as right now I am out of ideas.

Comment: you are missing the PHP part where you get the data posted

Comment: You're right, I was! Strangely it was actually working on my old server. Or maybe I am mistaken. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the variables with requests values and to concatenate this in query, like this:

```
$file_url = "\'http://path/to/{$new_image_name}\'";

$lat = $_REQUEST['lat'];
$lon = $_REQUEST['lon'];
$uname = $_REQUEST['uname'];

$insert = "INSERT INTO pins VALUES ('".$file_url."','".$lat."','".$lon."','".$uname."')";
```

Hope this helps.